# SharePoint List Relationship Question

Tags: list

I'm setting up a pet licensing application in SharePoint 2013.  It will use two lists, one for a list of pets, and one for a list of pet owners.  Both lists will relate to each other using the Pet Name column in the Pets list, and the Owner column in the Pet Owners list.  Each owner can have multiple pets, but each pet will only have one owner.

I'd like to configure the list so that once a pet has been associated with an owner, the Pet Owners list will display a list of pets associated with each owner; and so that the Pet will display its associated owner on its list.

Currently, when I associate a pet with an owner, the pets display on the Pet Owners list but the pet owner doesn't display on the Pets list; causing me to associate the items twice.

Does anyone know how I can configure relationships between these two lists without having to associate each item twice?